# Apache Cordova not Allowing me to run in visual studio

Tags: apache, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Every time i try to create a new app ( trying to look at cross platform apps) in visual studio I get this error:
[image]

I have installed the android SDK , is there something else I should be installing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you installed the android SDK but didn't run it to install the platform tools and the SDK APIs.

Run the "android" command on your computer, it will start the android SDK manager.
Then you have to install The android SDK tools and android platform for at least SDK 19.

One quick way is to just click the install button on the bottom right of the window, it should install automatically the latest SDK tools and paltform tools.

If you're short on disk space I recommend you uncheck all that's not usefull if you only want to use Cordova and not plan to do native dev :

- the samples
- the system images (unless you want to use the emulator, in this case just install one, don't need all)
- the documentations

Answer (score 0):

This is simply telling you that the x86 emulator system image is missing. If you do not plan on using the Android Emulator or will only be using an ARM image, you can ignore this warning.  We're working to ensure messaging is more nuanced in this area in the future.